# Why does this Powershell subexpression operator command not work?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to understand why a Powershell one liner I want to use to setup a port proxy to a WSL instance seemingly does not work, but running it without the grouping/substitution does work. Steps:

**Get the IP address of WSL instance:**

```
wsl hostname -I

> 172.18.108.185
```

**Try one liner with the previous command as subexpression:**

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=3443 `
listenaddress=0.0.0.0 connectport=3443 `
connectaddress=$(wsl hostname -I)
```

**That *seems* to work because listing port proxies shows it:**

```
netsh interface portproxy show v4tov4

> Listen on ipv4:             Connect to ipv4:
> 
> Address         Port        Address         Port
> --------------- ----------  --------------- ----------
> 0.0.0.0         3443        172.18.108.185  3443
```

(I have also tried it without the `$`.)

*However*, the proxy forwarding **does not actually work**.

**If I then do the same command without the substitution:**

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=3443 `
listenaddress=0.0.0.0 connectport=3443 `
connectaddress=172.18.108.185
```

**The output looks exactly the same:**

```
netsh interface portproxy show v4tov4

> Listen on ipv4:             Connect to ipv4:
> 
> Address         Port        Address         Port
> --------------- ----------  --------------- ----------
> 0.0.0.0         3443        172.18.108.185  3443
```

*However*, this time **it works**.

What is different between these two executions such that one works, one doesn't, and yet the results look exactly the same?

Comment: Are there any trailing or leading lines, or spaces? Try the `.Trim()` method:`( ..code.. ).Trim()` - *can use the sub-epxression operator as well*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Abraham Zinala](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14903754/abraham-zinala) provided the crucial pointer:

The output from `wsl hostname -I` - surprisingly - has a *trailing space*, which must be *trimmed* in order for the IP address represented by the output to be used as an argument passed to `netsh`:

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=3443 `
  listenaddress=0.0.0.0 connectport=3443 `
  connectaddress=$((wsl hostname -I).Trim())
```